# How to place a view above default title bar?

Tags: android, view

In my android application , i want to place a customized view above the default tilebar .could anyone  have a suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean by "default title bar"? the status bar, or some title bar that is in the app?

Comment: not the status bar, the title bar on which the title is set when we call the `setTitle()` method in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that it is possible. What you can do this, create everything on your own in your layout file and hide the default title bar. This way your layout file will have following three components one after another.

```
<the view you want to add above title bar>
             <Title bar>
      <Your general layout components>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`; to your Activity and design your own title bar and place it at the top of your screen.

Comment: no, i want the default title as well as the custom title. The custom title will display some stuff, and i want the default title to show indeterminent progress using `setProgressBarIndeterminate()`